# Unexpected token ')', rogue parantheses no where to be found

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, console, unexpected-token

I have a simple script that dynamically generates buttons. Clicking on a button generates an error message in the console: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' (at (index):1:8)". Why is this error being generated, and how do I prevent it?

```html
<button onclick="delete();">A Pet</button>
```

Comment: How does `console.log(data)` look like?

Comment: 3(index):21 This is data: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
:3000/favicon.ico:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' (at (index):1:8)  The first two bits showed up before I pressed the button.

Comment: Try to change const by var : var purchase = this.id;

Comment: So the data is coming alright. How does `console.log(data[0])` look like?. Also you didn't close the `<h2>` tag.

Comment: This is data: [object Object].  Closed the h2 tag, changed const to var.  Neither worked.

Comment: The given sample doesn't produce the given error for me. Please rewrite it as a [mcve]. Note you can use [SO Snippets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/90527) to create a [live example](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/90527) that runs from the question itself. Also, please include platform info (such as browser(s) used).

Comment: The `data[0]` should have been an `{object}` not a string `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 2):

`delete` is a keyword, and not valid as a function name. When the JS engine encounters `delete()` in the click handler body, it interprets it as a `delete` statement applied to `()`, which is an empty expression, and syntactically invalid.

To fix, use a non-keyword name. Note that it might be better to use [`addEventListener` instead of an inline handler](//stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/90527).